# How to force gcc to ignore localisation

Tags: c++, gcc

My localisation is set to german and gcc outputs german compiler warnings but codeblocks handles those warnings as errors and doesn't let me run my application. I got so far that I figured out that I need to force gcc to output english warnings but all answers I found were like "set your systems language to english" but I don't want to do so.
How can I force gcc to output compiler warnings in english without changing my entire system language?

Comment: Try executing `gcc` with the `LANG` environmental variable set to `en_US.UTF-8` (I don't know how to/if it's possible to do this in code-blocks)

Comment: or `LANG=C` or just unset `LANG`

Comment: Best solution for this in the end: Fix your warnings.

Comment: You'll have to file a bug report for codeblocks too. That sounds like a bug...

Comment: In order to fix that warning I would need to violate a license and in my opinion a "waning: this operation could't consume large amount of memory" warning can be slightly ignored. But also thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC uses the `LANG`, `LC_MESSAGES` and `LC_ALL` environment variables.

The most likely cause of GCC printing messags in German is that `LANG` is set to something like  `de_DE.UTF-8` so just unset that (or set it to the default POSIX locale, `C`,  or to an English locale such as `en_US`) before running GCC.

If you can't adjust the command-line that CodeBlocks uses to invoke the compiler then you should be able to adjust the environment before running codeblocks, e.g. instead of running `codeblocks` to start the IDE (or whatever the command to start the IDE is) run `LANG=C codeblocks`

That will alter the environment for the `codeblocks` process and any child processes it runs, including the compiler commands it runs.

If that doesn't work check maybe you have `LC_ALL` or `LC_MESSAGES` set in your environment (you can check with `echo "LC_ALL is $LC_ALL, LC_MESSAGES is $LC_MESSAGES";`) so you can just override that:

```
LC_ALL=C codeblocks
```